# Cannot define a MLFLOW experiment

Tags: python, mlflow

I want to use MLFlow to do some tracking but the code in the documentation's tutoriel doesn't work ?

Here's the code :

```
import mlflow
from mlflow.models import infer_signature

import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

mlflow.set_tracking_uri(uri="http://127.0.0.1:8080")
   
mlflow.set_experiment("MLflow Quickstart")
```

The result is a huge exception error, I will post here the end of it :

```
MlflowException: API request to http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name failed with exception HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=MLflow+Quickstart (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001B3EAE274D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée'))
```

It seems it has to do with some authorisation but I cannot figure it out what.

P.S : I also tried Databricks to avoid the trouble but I cannot create an account, it seems it's happening quite often, I asked for help on the official website but so far the solution provided didn't work. So for now I'm stuck with the local